# Access Google Cloud from Talend installed on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, integration, talend

Is it possible to access Google Cloud data (BigQuery) or any other cloud data store from Talend Data Fabric Installed on AWS Cloud?

Thanks
Raghu

Comment: Is there a reason you can think of why this wouldn't work?  If you are trying and it's not working, please show some code and error output.

Answer (score 1):

yes, this should not be an issue. usually more of a permissions issue